Ubuntu variant using less than 60MB of RAM
I've been trying to configure a Debian VM with minimum RAM utilization.  Using HTOP I've noticed the stable debian-12.5.0-amd64-DVD install consumes 68MB of RAM whereas the newer weekly build debian-testing-amd64-netinst consumes 62MB of RAM.  I'm looking at Ubuntu to see if there is a more stripped down version of Ubuntu which uses less RAM.  VirtualBox VM assigned RAM is 300MB.
Does Ubuntu offer any stripped down configurations using less than 60MB of RAM in a 300MB VM?

You can try Ubuntu Server. Alternatively, if you want a really lightweight system, use something like Alpine without GUI (Arch without GUI would work too, BTW).

Thanks Archisman.  If you could share any info on memory consumption of Ubuntu Server that would be great!  Alpine is interesting but didn't want to go with busybox.

I have not used Ubuntu Server. I once put Arch in a VM and memory consumption was <50 MB. I assume Ubuntu Server and Debian CLI will have similar memory requirement.

Arch is too bleeding edge for me but that is definitely better than what I'm seeing on Debian.

Are you really splitting hairs about 60 vs 62 MB of ram? I suppose the server also actually have to do something, and not just sit using as little ram as possible?

Yes.  I would like to remove unnecessary components.
